# Python Cucumber BDD package: Idiomatic way to inject the functionality that you would like to test

Tags: python, python-3.x, cucumber, bdd, gherkin

I have completed the tutorials for BDD with Python Cucumber on Udemy [Here](https://www.udemy.com/course/bdd-testing-with-python).

However, in these lessons, the tutor implements the step definitions with functionality that has already been implemented. To me, this defeats the purpose of BDD. I want to write the tests before I write the code that should make the tests pass.

The way I have attempted to do this is to use a config file, i.e in `Config.py`:

```
myFunctionality = {
    "doMyThing" : lambda : assert(false)
}
```

And then in the step implementation file:

```
from Config import Config

@when('We request to do my thing')
def step_impl(context):
context.result = Config.myFunctionality.get("doMyThing")()
```

Once I have written all of my tests, I can write the logic for `doMyThing()`, and then simply edit the `Config.py` file, i.e:

```
From CoreLogic import CoreLogic

myFunctionality = {
    "doMyThing" : lambda : CoreLogic.doMyThing()
}
```

This means I can use the same set of Cucumber tests for my prototype and my final implementation. All I would have to do is edit the config file.

Is this a good way to go about this? Surely this is a very common use case, so how do people usually inject the functionality they would like to test into Cucumber?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Step definitions are not tests. The cucumber scenarios are the tests. Nothing is preventing you from writing the scenarios with no step definitions.

Some BDD frameworks will fail a test with unimplemented steps. To avoid this, stub each new step out in such a manner that it marks the test "pending" or "inconclusive". That way continuous integration builds will continue passing while you implement the application infrastructure to support the step definitions.

Comment: Cucumber will fail an unimplemented step. But it still seems like a lot of work, having to remember to update your step definition every time you update your application infrastructure.

Comment: @Blue7: Even with your proposed solution you are editing something. You just aren't changing a step definition. You are building a layer between the step definitions and your infrastructure classes, and this layer needs to be updated if your infrastructure is updated. It's the same problem, but you are introducing another layer of complexity that is unnecessary. If you need common logic between steps, you can always add functions or use your infrastructure classes. No need for a whole different layer just to stub out functionality.

Comment: True, you have a point. I was just trying to minimise the amount of changes. I'm brand new to cucumber so I'm still learning what "good design" is.